# How to use character mask in hashcat?

Tags: brute-force, password-cracking, hashcat

I do not get hashcat working the way I want.

I got this handshake captured file. I can crack it with `?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a --increment` but since I know the password is between 14 and 16 charters that is unnecessary work. Therefore I am trying to use `?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a --increment-min 14 --increment-max 16`.

But it is complaining about `?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a` being too much and I know that the password only contain lowercase, numbers, and these usual symbols: `(!_-,.:;/)`.

How do I make this custom mask to only use relevant information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed too large of a keyspace. ?a is 95 characters. 95^14 is 4x10^27, which won't be exhausted any time soon.

If you want to reduce the possible characters as you describe, use a custom character set:

```
hashcat -1 '?l?d!_-,.:;/' ?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1
```

But even this keyspace 44^14, or 1x10^23 - too large to reasonably exhaust.

Unless you can narrow down your keyspace further, brute force won't help you here.

Comment: But if I begin with a 8 char keyspace and use --increment, will it still increase and eventually crack 15 charters passwords or will it stop when I becomes too large?

Comment: If it is truly random, the 15-character length won't be reached for years. Especially if you're working with a WPA2 handshake, because it is a pretty slow hash.